# Xaml Multibinding or string concatenation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to efficiently construct the url for an image. This image is part of a large collection of items where each item only contains the image url suffix. The object that contains the collection has the base url (see below).

```
public class MyItems
{
    public string ImageUrlBase {get;set;}
    public List<MyItem> Items {get;set;}
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string ImageUrlSuffix {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Now, I'm displaying these items in a ListBox and I need to get the combined string of the `ImageUrlBase` and `ImageUrlSuffix` as the image source in the `ListBoxItem` (see below)

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding FullImageUrl}" />     <!-- need full url here -->
                <StackPanel MaxWidth="390">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Short from adding a property to the `MyItem` class and manually setting the full Url, I'm stumped as to what my options are. I'm deserializing the `MyItems` object, including the child list of `MyItem` objects with it so I don't believe a custom constructor would work. Iterating over the list of `MyItem` objects seems extremely inefficient, but I don't know a better way.

Any tips?

Comment: One approach to consider: use an `IValueConverter` that inherits `DependencyObject`, with a dependency property for "ImageUrlBase".  The catch is that you have to worry about timing -- the "ImageBaseUrl" has to bind before any of the items, as the change to the converter DP won't trigger a refresh of the item properties.

Comment: Also, you *could* use MultiBinding, as in the CodeProject example linked.  This does present its own challenges though, as there is no `AncestorType` binding in WP Silverlight.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286171/MultiBinding-in-Silverlight-5

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution would be to do something like this:

```
public class MyItems
{
       public string ImageUrlBase { get; set; }
       public List<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string ImageUrlSuffix { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public MyItems Parent { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return Parent.ImageUrlBase + ImageUrlSuffix;
        }
    }
}
```

You just can't simply do multibinding nor you could do some converter that would fetch "parent" `DataContext` so you have to construct it yourself.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks.